# Concatenate from .properties into an output file

Tags: ant, build, concatenation

I tried to concatenate a file name and version number.

The version is  from local.properties

```
sdk.dir=E:/Android/android-sdk-windows
sdk.version=1.6
```

My ant file build_factory.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project name="Main release build" default="release" basedir="..">

    <target name="configFactory">
        <echo message="sdk.dir=f:/build/android-sdk-windows" file="build/local.properties" />
    </target>

    <target name="release">

        <ant antfile="build/build_sdk_platform.xml" target="build_prod" />
        <ant antfile="build/build_sdk.xml" target="javadocs" />
        <ant antfile="build/build_sample.xml" target="prepareSources" />        
        <tar basedir="workspace" destfile="MapAndroidSDK-${sdk.version}.tar" />

    </target>
```

What I want at the end is the file named MapAndroidSDK-1.6.jar. Everything is built except the .tar file

[Edit] 
In the end , the tar is named MapAndroidSDK-${sdk.version}.tar instead of MapAndroidSDK-1.6.tar

In the console, I get  :

```
modify_path:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to c:\hudson\workspace\emb-android-sdk-trunk\MapSample\libs
     [copy] Copying 1 file to c:\hudson\workspace\emb-android-sdk-trunk\MapSample
     [copy] Copying 1 file to c:\hudson\workspace\emb-android-sdk-trunk\MapSample
     [copy] Copying 179 files to c:\hudson\workspace\emb-android-sdk-trunk\workspace\MapSample
      [tar] Building tar: c:\hudson\workspace\emb-android-sdk-trunk\MapAndroidSDK-${sdk.version}.tar
      [tar] Entry: doc/com/Map/resource/proto/class-use/LocationByQueryRequestProtos.LocationByQueryRequest.Builder.html longer than 100 characters.
      [tar] Resulting tar file can only be processed successfully by GNU compatible tar commands
      [tar] Entry: doc/com/Map/resource/proto/class-use/ServiceCategoriesRequestProtos.ServiceCategoriesRequest.Builder.html longer than 100 characters.
      [tar] Entry: doc/com/Map/resource/proto/class-use/ServiceCategoriesResponseProtos.ServiceCategoriesResponse.Builder.html longer than 100 characters.
      [tar] Entry: doc/com/Map/resource/proto/class-use/ServiceCategoriesResponseProtos.ServiceCategoriesResponse.html longer than 100 characters.
```

Comment: So what happens when you try?

Comment: I just edited ! The ouput is AndroidSDK-${sdk.version}.tar instead of AndroidSDK-1.6.tar

Comment: What is reading `local.properties`?

Comment: local.properties only contains : "sdk.dir=E:/Android/android-sdk-windows
sdk.version=1.6"

Comment: Yes, but where in your Ant script are you *reading* that file?  It's not read by magic.

Comment: You mean I should add <property file="build/local.properties" /> in the project tree ? Done

Comment: Thanks , I added the property line. Now it's working !! I or you shall post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read `local.properties`:

```
<property file="local.properties"/>
```

After you can use `sdk.version`